# How can I update some Docker containers on request without logging in via SSH?

Tags: docker, updates, frontend

I have some Docker containers in my home server and some of them are automatically updated via "watchtower" tool.

Other ones are not because are critical and I need to read the release notes first, because I want to be sure that nothing breaks upon update.

Right now to update those I need to connect via SSH and update those containers manually.

How can I avoid this? are there tools (or even Docker containers) which offer a web interface (on the local network) where I can update containers with a click? I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I thought I could also send a special email to myself with a command in it which will be recognised by a use mail filter and used to run a specific script, but maybe there are easier solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a web interface for your Docker daemon, you might want to try [Portainer](https://www.portainer.io/).

Alternatively you might want to configure the Docker daemon and your local machine to be able to connect to your remote Docker daemon with your local Docker CLI via TCP or SSH like so:

```
docker -H tcp://dockerhost:2375 run ...
docker -H ssh://docker run ...
```

See details [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option).